# How to get response data (sid) in Jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My Test Plan (not working):

```
+ WebSocket Sampler
  - Regular Expression Extractor
```

**My Regular Expression:**

[image]

**Response data:**

```
[Message 1]
0{"sid":"1BdTy3e4-jfrVM67AAAR","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}
```

How to get 'sid' ?

Comment: Regular expression `"sid":"(.+?)"` is ok. Try use `Match no(0 for Random) = 1`

Comment: See here https://regex101.com/r/yW4oR3/1

Comment: It work for me, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expression `"sid":"(.+?)"` is ok.

Try use `Match no(0 for Random) = 1`

For Regex test see here https://regex101.com/r/yW4oR3/1

Answer (score 4):

If you add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) after your request and look into the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, you will see that your Regular Expression returns only one match:

[image: Regular Expression Matches]

As per [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) documentation:

> **Match No.**  Indicates which match to use. The regular expression may match multiple times.
>
> - Use a value of zero to indicate JMeter should choose a match at random.
> - **A positive number N means to select the nth match.**
> - Negative numbers are used in conjunction with the ForEach Controller - see below.

Hence your **Match No:** setting is incorrect, you need either to remove `3` or change it to `1`

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more information on identifying the cause of your JMeter test failure